# Action Controller: Exception private method `sub' called for nil:NilClass

Tags: routes, ruby-on-rails-3.1, actioncontroller

I have got bare minimum in my app right now. I dont know why I am getting this error but if I look at log file it says this :-

> ActionController::RoutingError (private method `sub' called for nil:NilClass):
>     app/controllers/application_controller.rb:1
>     app/controllers/pages_controller.rb:1

My application controller does not contain anything (only protect_from_forgery) and my pages controller has few empty action at this moment.

Any pointers of what going wrong here?

**Update**

Since I had just started the project I was able to roll it back and start over again. However I am still clueless why this problem occured
Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Doublecheck your helpers -- the module names being defined need to match the helper's filename.